# Эффект переворачивания картинки при наведении

Tags: javascript

Можно ли на javascript (без флэша) сделать эффект переворачивания как вот здесь?  http://www.templatemonster.com/flash-templates/35762.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да. Легко:

```
$('image').mouseover(function(){animate({height: 0},200)});
```

Это вкратце. =)

```
<div class='imgcontainer'>
<img src='pantera1.jpg' style='height: 0' />
<img src='pantera2.jpg' style='height: 200px' />
</div>

<script>
$('.imgcontainer').mouseover(function(){
$(this).children('img').first().animate({height:'200px'},200);
$(this).children('img').last().animate({height:'0'},200);
}).mouseout(function(){
$(this).children('img').last().animate({height:'200px'},200);
$(this).children('img').first().animate({height:'0'},200);
});
</script>
```

Это полностью для одной плашки. Плашек может быть сколько угодно.
Если нигде не ошибся, должно работать.
200px меняете на реальную высоту рисунка

Comment: Ну, полностью - как-то так. Требует jquery.

Comment: желательно еще поставить в стиль для див блока
.imgcontainer {overflow:hidden;}

Comment: консоль ошибок не показывает, но скрипт не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Можно это сделать с помощью CSS3, без JS

Comment: подскажи как? :)

Answer (score 0):

css3
например

```
#image{-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;}

#image:hover {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(2);}
```